# Ajax request retrieve Json

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I'm using `Laravel 4` and I have the following problem. I make an `Ajax`request and I have a class `GpsController` with function a called `GPSOnline`.

```
 public function GPSOnline () {
   $gpsonline=File::get( Config::get('app.driverspath'));
   $fstep = explode("|", $gpsonline);
   foreach($fstep as $k => $v){
      if(strlen($v)>0){
         $sstep [] = explode(",", $v);
      }
   }

   $array = array();
   foreach ($sstep as $v) {
     $tmp['ch'] = substr($v[0],0,1);
     $tmp['poz'] = substr($v[0],1);
     $tmp['la'] = $v[1];
     $tmp['lo'] = $v[2];
     $array[] = $tmp;
   } 

  // echo json_encode($array);
  return Response::json(array($array));
 }
```

But it didn't work.What's wrong in my code?!

Comment: Describe more what you get as a result.What is the outcome of the `ajax` request?Do you get any result?Does the request reach your route and controller?

Comment: I should get an  associative array as a result like this:
[{"login":"199","ch":"1","poz":"99","la":"48.303017","lo":"38.041583"},{"login":"370","ch":"3","poz":"70","la":"48.297291","lo":"38.0153"},{"login":"399","ch":"3","poz":"99","la":"48.308815","lo":"38.02129"},{"login":"1209","ch":"1","poz":"209","la":"48.31639","lo":"37.964965"},{"login":"122","ch":"1","poz":"22","la":"48.338839","lo":"37.97747"},{"login":"3142","ch":"3","poz":"142","la":"48.305961","lo":"38.033485"},{"login":"1284","ch":"1","poz":"284","la":"48.34223","lo":"37.97"}]

Comment: 1.What is the outcome of the ajax request? -  

Сontacting the link to my controller 

2.Do you get any result? - No, I don,t. 

3.Does the request reach your route and controller? - How can I check this?

Comment: What is the status code of the `ajax` request?`JQuery` has a pretty convenient way to deal with unsuccesful requests. Next,a dumb way is to `echo` something just to see if it reachs your controller,or use a closure function inside your route to see if it reaches it.

Comment: Because find what the problem is kind of difficult you have to split the problem. You have to see if the problem is on your `ajax` request,your route your controller OR in the content inside the controller,try to `log` the outcome of the actions indside your controller.